# Is there any way to embed browser component into game for facebook Authentication?

Tags: facebook

Say I have desktop game and I like to make it social, for that I need browser component 
embedded into my game  ( c++ openGL) for the Authentication part. Is there any framework 
for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried myself, but you can find some C++ libraries.

- C++ FaceBook REST Client (which seems very simple to use.):
   http://projects.seligstein.com/facebook/
- Facebook cpp Api (which seems to use Qt):
   http://code.google.com/p/facebook-cpp-graph-api/
- Fantasma (which seems to use Qt too):
   http://launchpad.net/fantasma

Comment: ok thanks it seams that only the second option is valid and up to date :
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-cpp-graph-api/